# Enumerate item label not aligned

Tags: enumerate, itemize

I have a list of things separated by sections. As follow:

[image]

To do that I define my own label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[$\bullet$]First Title
    \item First item
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\circ$}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Test
            \item Two
        \end{itemize}
    \item Second item
\item[$\bullet$] Second Title
    \item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But as you can see the bullet and the number below are not aligned.

I was trying to find how to nest `itemize` and `enumerate` but I don't think that's possible.

I also don't mind if I indent the numbered labels. I tried to add a \quad before \item but I was hacking my way through it and didn't work lol.

I went through http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/enumerate.pdf but I'm not sure how to handles macros. I tried to add the option `\@enSpace` within the bracket `[]` but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you please add a description or probably better a sketch of the desired output?

Comment: @leandriis I added a square to make it more obvious that it is not aligned. Does it helps?

Comment: they are both right aligned in the space the right edge of the bullet and the right edge of the . in such cases often best to adjust "by eye" so `\textbullet\hspace{2pt}` or whatever looks right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `align=left, labelwidth=1ex` as arguments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
% To set the options globally, uncomment the next line
%\setlist[enumerate]{align=left, labelwidth=1ex}
\begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
    \noindent Normal:
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item[$\bullet$]First Title
      \item First item
      \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\circ$}
      \begin{enumerate}[]
        \item Test
        \item Two
      \end{enumerate}
      \item Second item
      \item[$\bullet$] Second Title
      \item Third item
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \noindent With \verb|align=left, labelwidth=1ex|:
    \begin{enumerate}[align=left, labelwidth=1ex]
      \item[$\bullet$]First Title
      \item First item
      \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\circ$}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item Test
        \item Two
      \end{enumerate}
      \item Second item
      \item[$\bullet$] Second Title
      \item Third item
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```